# Run time error in castalia during network initialization

Tags: omnet++

[Dear castalia users i tried a lot to solving this error but i am unable to fix this error. can any one gave exact solution how to resolve error given in figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Qpl.png)

Comment: Improve your question after you take a look at [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If your simulation stops at 0 seconds, then it might be caused by some error in `intialize()` function.

Something that is impossible to be executed.

I had the same error when i was trying to get the transmission level.